# Exporting ASPX page to Excel, Need Multiple Worksheets

Tags: asp.net

I am exporting an aspx page as an xls (excel) file.

I have everything working fine, but am wondering if there is a way to section some data from the aspx page into different excel worksheets?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about how you export the data, which technique you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I export data from an ASP.NET page to Excel:

http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/creating-downloadable-content-dynamically

If you have something else in mind, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: This is how I do it, but is there a way to export into multiple worksheets?

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure this is not possible. CSV only supports raw data and has no syntax for controlling any Excel formatting or worksheet information.